# What is the difference between Presence getType() and isAvailable() in Smack?

Tags: xmpp, chat, smack

I am trying to get the Presence of users in my chat roster using asmack.
From what i understand, Presece.getType() should return one of these presence types:

Every presence packet has a type, which is one of the following values:

```
available -- (Default) indicates the user is available to receive messages.
unavailable -- the user is unavailable to receive messages.
subscribe -- request subscription to recipient's presence.
subscribed -- grant subscription to sender's presence.
unsubscribe -- request removal of subscription to sender's presence.
unsubscribed -- grant removal of subscription to sender's presence.
error -- the presence packet contains an error message.
```

Using Presence.getType() on my presence object for an online user gives me this:

```
Log.e("Presence?",myRoster.getPresence(entry.getUser()).getType().toString());

Unavailable
```

However, using Presence.isAvailable() on the same user gives me:

```
Log.e("Presence?",Boolean.toString(myRoster.getPresence(entry.getUser()).isAvailable()));

True
```

Shouldn't getType() and isAvailable() return me the same results according to the following definitions?

```
public Presence.Type getType()
```

Returns the type of this presence packet.

```
public boolean isAvailable()
```

Returns true if the presence type is available (online) and false if the user is unavailable (offline), or if this is a presence packet involved in a subscription operation. This is a convenience method equivalent to getType() == Presence.Type.available.

What am I missing? What's the difference between the two?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source you will find that

```
public boolean isAvailable() {
    return type == Type.available;    
}
```

also the [javadoc of isAvailable()](https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/packet/Presence.html#isAvailable%28%29) states that

> This is a convenience method equivalent to getType() ==
>   Presence.Type.available.

Comment: Thanks Flow. So if presence.isAvailable() returns True, that implies type = available. However presence.getType() on the same presence object returns "Unavailable". How can we account for this disparity?

Comment: Likely because it's not the same presence instance.